# Add a NEXT button to a Split View Controller

Tags: ipad, view, split, uisplitviewcontroller

2 days of reading every posting i could get my hands on with no luck.  Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a standard split view controller that loads a new view controller on the Right for each item you choose on the Left.  Standard easy stuff.  Now the "impossible part".  I have added a big button in the middle of each detail view controller.  I want to click the button and have it automatically advance to the next view (simulating someone actually clicking the next item in the root view in the left).

A bonus would be to actually have the left root view side also highlight the next row in the list when the button is hit.

I'd pay fifty bucks for working sample code "not much I know".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably read the ViewController Programming tutorial...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1